# Google Earth tour LookAt not looking at same place as Placemark with same coordinates

Tags: kml, coordinates, google-earth

I have tried to create a tour from a csv file. I want the tour to look at each Placemark in turn but the view is of a different set of locations when run in Google Earth. The Placemarks are plotting correctly (as far as I can tell) and the LookAt seems to be off. Please could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<Document>
   <name>Test</name>
   <open>1</open>
   <gx:Tour>
   <name>Play me!</name>
   <gx:Playlist>
   <gx:FlyTo>
   <gx:duration>10</gx:duration>
   <LookAt>
       <longtitude>-0.0441561</longtitude>
       <latitude>51.4354051</latitude>
       <altitude>400</altitude>
       <heading>1</heading>
       <tilt>0</tilt>
       <range>1</range>
       <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
   </LookAt>
   </gx:FlyTo>
           <gx:wait>
               <gx:duration>10</gx:duration>
           </gx:wait>
   <gx:FlyTo>
   <gx:duration>10</gx:duration>
   <LookAt>
       <longtitude>-0.0382701</longtitude>
       <latitude>51.452901</latitude>
       <altitude>400</altitude>
       <heading>1</heading>
       <tilt>0</tilt>
       <range>1</range>
       <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
   </LookAt>
   </gx:FlyTo>
           <gx:wait>
               <gx:duration>10</gx:duration>
           </gx:wait>
   <gx:FlyTo>
   <gx:duration>10</gx:duration>
   <LookAt>
       <longtitude>-0.0242591</longtitude>
       <latitude>51.4303771</latitude>
       <altitude>400</altitude>
       <heading>1</heading>
       <tilt>0</tilt>
       <range>1</range>
       <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
   </LookAt>
   </gx:FlyTo>
           <gx:wait>
               <gx:duration>10</gx:duration>
           </gx:wait>

    <gx:TourControl>
    </gx:TourControl>
   </gx:Playlist>
   </gx:Tour>
 <Placemark>
       <name>T1</name>
       <description></description>
       <Point>
           <coordinates>-0.0441561,51.4354051</coordinates>
       </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
       <name>T2</name>
       <description></description>
       <Point>
           <coordinates>-0.0382701,51.452901</coordinates>
       </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
       <name>T3</name>
       <description></description>
       <Point>
           <coordinates>-0.0242591,51.4303771</coordinates>
       </Point>
   </Placemark>
</Document>
```

Comment: This is clearly a case of "a problem that ... went away when a typo was fixed" (see the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry everyone, I was miss-spelling 'longitude' as 'longtitude' and so the (not valid) tag was silently ignored by the parser.

Comment: I believe OP _is_ providing an answer to OP's question.